# Cannot return data from IMAGE_CAPTURE intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to understand `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE` intent. If I call:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
 startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

Camera app is launched, I can take a picture but the camera app does not close unless I click the back button, that does not return any result.
How can I force the camera app to return to my app after a photo has been taken?

Answer (score 1):

You have to recieve the Data from the "returning Intent"

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0){
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras(); } }
```

I don't know any possibility to kill the other activity

Comment: The problem is that onActivityResult is fired only when the back button is clicked; when i make a photo i cannot close the Camera app in other way.

Comment: Yea. As mentioned i know no way to achieve that. The only possible solution is to use the camera object to take the photo manualy

Comment: It's very strange because there are a lot of examples that do not talk about using the camera object, it seems to be possible to take a photo using intent filter

Comment: try experimenting with requestCodes, maybe the solution lies there